# JSF f:event execution order

Tags: jsf-2

Suppose I have multiple f:event tags to process the same kind of event:

```
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{myBean.action1()} />
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{myBean.action2()} />
```

Is the order of execution guaranteed?

**Edit:**
To clarify why I need them to be executed in specific order, here is my use case:

myBean#action1 is actually a setter

myBean#action2 is a method that operates on a field set by action1

In my opinion, the order is unreliable, that's why I simply put them as `EL expressions` inside my facelet like this:

```
<p:ouputPanel>
  #{myBean.action1()}
  #{myBean.action2()}
</p:ouputPanel>
```

Comment: Dunno, but you can always can guarantee it by 100% if you place one f:event only in which you call the action2 from action1 :)

Comment: Can't do that. I need to pass different parameters to those `action` methods. And the methods are not logically related. I know there are some other alternatives, but I'm just curious whether I can rely on order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [spec](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr314/index.html) doesn't seem to explicitly state that anywhere.

The [`Application#publishEvent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/Application.html#publishEvent%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Object%29) API mentions that they are obtained and processed as a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) which is by nature ordered. Both the [Mojarra](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.faces/jsf-api/2.1.7/javax/faces/component/UIViewRoot.java#1557) and [MyFaces](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.myfaces.core/myfaces-api/2.1.6/javax/faces/component/UIViewRoot.java#1247) implementations confirms this by storing them in a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` and `ArrayList` respectively.

So, logically based on the the API and the both implementations, they are indeed executed in order, if added to the same parent UI component.

Comment: Thanks! Your opinion is highly appreciated as usual ;)