# Multiple <f:event> tags

Tags: events, jsf-2, listeners

Can I have multiple  tags in a Jsf2 xhtml file?

In that case in what order will the associated listeners be called?

Mojarra 2.1.1 / Apache Tomcat 7.0.22 / PrimeFaces 3.4

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can have multiple `<f:event>` tags in a xhtml page.The execution order really depends on the `type` of event you define in the `<f:event>` tag.Check [here](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.1/vdldocs/facelets/f/event.html) for more types .So, far I have worked with `type=preRenderView` which renders in the sequentail order if you have multiple events

Ex:

```
 <f:event listener="#{bean.method1}" type="preRenderView"> // executes first

 <f:event listener="#{bean.method2}" type="preRenderView"> // execues after above tag
```

There are other events which `type` attribute in the `<f:event>` tag takes . Go through this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999099/jsf-execution-order-of-fevents) to learn more about event types :

Comment: thank you, think m getting an error on the same, will check and get back ... but read somewhere that execution order is not guaranteed and no concrete answer there if we can use multiple time in the first place ...

Comment: Check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147261/jsf-fevent-execution-order